# Error called"NoClassDEFFoundError "comes when running a applet

Tags: java, applet

Hey guys i have a problem that has been wasting my times for hours which is that i get an error saying "NoClassDEFFoundError Wrong name(bigFish/BigFish)" when i try to run my html file which include a class and that contains a applet. bigFish is my project name and package name. BigFish is my class name of the class which contains the applet. and i have located my html file called BigFish in where the BigFish class file is located. how to do this. this comes in firefox. and i can't shift to chrome. its not working since month a back(doesn't even open). how can i see my applet run on web?

Comment: put your html file outside the package of the class file.

Comment: then it says no BigFish class found

Comment: reference class of the BigFish is also there but it says nodefClass

Comment: Please stop writing comments like that. If you have something constructive edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..i have located my html file called BigFish in where the BigFish class file is located.

That probably won't work.  A loose class file in the `bigFish` package needs to be in a similarly named directory of the server.  So, assuming the HTML is in directory `www` on the server, the structure should look something like this:

- `www` **directory**

  1. `bigFish` **directory**

     - `BigFish.class`
  2. `BigFish.html`

Comment: hey got it Solved when programming there shouldn't be a package created just a project name and then there must be the class that includes the applet. then it worked thanks

Comment: *"just a project name"*  That is mixing up 'IDE terms' with the 'real world'.  The real worlds understands directories and packages (the package name must equal the directory).